# Should a class also be responsible for storing itself's data to db?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class named Rectangle and it has some attributes like: color, width, height etc. So this class will for sure describe this object but I also want to save this object to database and later read and create object from db.

My question is should this class also have methods like "SaveRectangle", "GetOneRectangle ", "GetAllRectangles", "EditRectangle" that handles the SQL operations or is there a other good practice?

Comment: There are several patterns for storing data. The way you architect your objects depends on which pattern you decide to use. What you are describing is commonly known as the Active Record pattern. The opposite would be the Data Mapper pattern (which is where a secondary object handles storing/retrieving data from the database).

Comment: No.  A class might know how to serialize itself to XML/JSON/etc., but the actually data layer should only be accessed by another object, such as a `RectangleRepository` object.  This way you can easily support saving your objects to a file, a REST web service or SQL, by simply making a new repository object.

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question.  You may want to do some research on design patterns.

Comment: According to SOLID principles (see http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), if you want to follow the Single Responsibility Principle there should only be one reason to change an object. If you put your persistence into this object, there would be two reasons - one to change what data is in the object, and another to change how the data is persisted. You would then be breaking that principle. Of course, these principles are guidelines that don't always have to be followed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you check out [Martin Fowler's "Patterns of Enterprise Architecture"](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/).

There are several different patterns for data persistence. The pattern you describe is "Active Record". It can definitely make things easier in the short term but I have found that it often leads to issues when working with many objects.

I typically choose to use a combination of the "Data Mapper" and "Table Data Gateway" patterns that separates storage/retrieval concerns from the objects themselves. That allows me to handle both separately and, possibly, more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have to say that it is my first time on stackoverflow and I am amaze how fast and easy it is to get some information.